# Динамическое обновление данных из таблицы

Tags: php, ajax, phpmyadmin, redbeanphp

Подскажите, не совсем получается сделать динамическое обновление из одной таблицы в другую.
Данные надо перенести из таблицы Users в таблицу Levels.
Некий код написал

```
function getExpToNextExp_up($user_id)
{
    $query = R::getRow("SELECT `levels`.`exp_up` FROM levels 
                        JOIN `users` ON `users`.`lvl` = `levels`.`lvl` 
                        WHERE `users`.`id` = {$user_id}");
    return $query['exp_up'];
}

function getExpToHereExp_up($user_exp_up, $user_lvl)
{
    $query = R::getRow("SELECT {$user_exp_up} - exp_up FROM levels 
                        WHERE lvl = {$user_lvl}");
    return $query["{$user_exp_up} - exp_up"];
}
```

Вот до этого момента через вар дамп все отображается. Но почему-то перед значением вылетает "-80" вот так например

где exp_up - опыт до нового уровня, lvl- уровень. Вот до этого все работает, но почему выдает выражение с минусом через вар дамп.
Дальше делаю  вот этот код

```
function updateUserExp_up($user_id, $user_exp_up)
{
    $update_to_exp_up = R::getRow("SELECT MAX(exp_up) FROM `levels` WHERE lvl => {$user_lvl}");
    R::exec('UPDATE `users` SET `exp_up` = :exp_up WHERE id = :id', [
        'id' => $user_id,
        'exp-up' => $update_to_exp_up['MAX(exp_up)']
    ]);
    
    $user = R::load('users', $user_id);
    return $user;
  }
```

и соответственно в init.php

Переменная

```
updateUserExp_up($user->id, $user->exp_up);
```

Но перестает работать и выдает ошибку Fatal error: Uncaught [42000] - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>' at line 1 trace: #0 D:\OpenServer\domains\vargs.mobi\libs\redbean\rb-mysql.php(1080): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->runQuery() #1 D:\OpenServer\domains\vargs.mobi\libs\redbean\rb-mysql.php(1148): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetAll() #2 D:\OpenServer\domains\vargs.mobi\libs\redbean\rb-mysql.php(4185): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->GetRow() #3 D:\OpenServer\domains\vargs.mobi\libs\redbean\rb-mysql.php(11645): RedBeanPHP\Adapter\DBAdapter->getRow() #4 D:\OpenServer\domains\vargs.mobi\libs\redbean\rb-mysql.php(12764): RedBeanPHP\Facade::query() #5 D:\OpenServer\domains\vargs.mobi\core\functions.php(97): RedBeanPHP\Facade::getRow() #6 D:\OpenServer\domains\vargs.mobi\init.php(37): updateUserExp_up() #7 D:\OpenServer\domains\vargs.mobi\index.php(3): include_once('D:\OpenServer\d...') #8 {main} thrown in D:\OpenServer\domains\vargs.mobi\libs\redbean\rb-mysql.php on line 810.

Исправил переменную на 1 код заработал, как и следует.

```
function updateUserExp_up($user_id, $user_lvl)
{
    $update_to_exp_up = R::getRow("SELECT MAX(exp_up) FROM `levels` WHERE lvl <= 1");
    R::exec('UPDATE `users` SET `exp_up` = :exp_up WHERE id = :id', [
        'id' => $user_id,
        'exp_up' => $update_to_exp_up['MAX(exp_up)']
    ]);
```

Но только стоит изменить на

Comment: Сравнение "больше или равно" `>=` , а не стрелка `=>`

Comment: Где-то допустил ошибку пока не пойму.

Comment: Это не помагает

Comment: переменная `$user_lvl` не существует, поэтому запрос у вас получается `... FROM levels WHERE lvl >=` - не очень похоже на корректный синтаксис

Comment: Запросы SELECT с подстановкой, нужно делать также, как и запросы UPDATE. SQL-injection можно делать не только в запросы UPDATE

Comment: ЧТо-то запутался с ними) надо перекур взять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getExpToNextExp_up($user_id)
{
    $query = R::getRow("SELECT `levels`.`exp_up` FROM levels 
                        JOIN `users` ON `users`.`lvl` = `levels`.`lvl` 
                        WHERE `users`.`id` = {$user_id}");
    return $query['exp_up'];
}

function getExpToHereExp_up($user_exp_up, $user_lvl)
{
    $query = R::getRow("SELECT {$user_lvl} - lvl FROM levels 
                        WHERE exp_up = {$user_exp}");
    return $query["{$user_exp_up} - lvl"];
}



function updateUserExp_up($user_id, $user_lvl)
{
    $update_to_exp_up = R::getRow("SELECT MAX(exp_up) FROM `levels` WHERE lvl <={$user_lvl} ");
    R::exec('UPDATE `users` SET `exp_up` = :exp_up WHERE id = :id', [
        'id' => $user_id,
        'exp_up' => $update_to_exp_up['MAX(exp_up)']
    ]);
    
    $user = R::load('users', $user_id);
    return $user;
  }
```

Переменная
updateUserExp_up($user->id, $user->lvl);
Спасибо за подсказку! Все заработало!